# How to fix this exception?

Tags: c++

I'm having problems again with my Euclid's algorithm problem. I'm running this on MS Visual Studio as a console application. When I run it, it says "process is terminated due stack overflow exception."

I've recently posted another question about this algorithm, but now I've got this problem and it's the first time I've seen it. I'm a beginner programmer.

```
int algoritmoeuclides(int a,int b)
{
if (a%b==0)
return b;
return algoritmoeuclides(b,a%b);
}

std::pair<int, int>division(int dividendo,int divisor)
{
    int resultado=0;
    int residuo=0;
    residuo=dividendo%divisor;
    resultado=dividendo/divisor;
    return std::pair<int, int>(residuo,resultado);
}

std::pair<int, int>EuclidesExtendido(int a,int b)
{
    int q,r,s,t;
    if (b == 0)
    return std::pair<int, int>(1, 0);
    else
        {
        std::pair<int, int>(q, r) = division(a, b);
        std::pair<int, int>(s, t) = EuclidesExtendido(b, r);
        }
        return std::pair<int, int>(t, s - q * t);
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
int a=525;
int b=231;
int s,t;
std::pair<int, int>(s, t)=EuclidesExtendido(a,b);
printf("%d",algoritmoeuclides(a,b));
printf("s=%d  t=%d",s,t);

getch();
}
```

Comment: This is not c, make sure to tag correctly please.

Comment: You should use the debugger (or print statements) to determine the flow of your program, and see whether it matches your intention.

Comment: Is that a legitimate declaration for `main()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I thought the same thing.  Apparently its a managed reference or handle in MS's C++/CLI or .net.  I just ignored it =)

Comment: @jedwards: OK - thanks for the information.  I think, given that `args` is unused, I'd recommend the classic `int main()` here, but I there's no need for further comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're collecting the return value of your functions incorrectly.

Despite having two values, a pair is a single object.  So

```
std::pair<int, int>(q, r) = division(a, b);
```

Should be something like:

```
std::pair<int, int> qr = division(a, b);
```

And then you could get `q` and `r` individually with:

```
int q = qr.first;
int r = qr.second;
```

You would need to make this sort of change everywhere that you have similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile the code with GNU `g++`, having commented out the `getch()`, changed the definition of `main()` to the simpler `int main()` (since the code doesn't use any arguments), and added the `<cstdio>` and `<utility>` headers, I get the extensive warnings:

```
euc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
euc.cpp:43:1: warning: ‘s’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
euc.cpp: In function ‘std::pair<int, int> EuclidesExtendido(int, int)’:
euc.cpp:23:5: warning: ‘r’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
euc.cpp:28:60: warning: ‘r’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
euc.cpp:30:44: warning: ‘q’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
euc.cpp:30:44: warning: ‘t’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
euc.cpp:30:44: warning: ‘s’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
euc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
euc.cpp:40:29: warning: ‘s’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
euc.cpp:40:29: warning: ‘t’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

You should turn up the warning level on MS Visual Studio so you see such warnings and can fix them before submitting questions here.  Given that you are using uninitialized variables, you are getting quasi-random values to play with, which is probably driving your system into the recursion far deeper than you expected, leading to the stack overflow.

---

This code compiles and runs without self-evident problems on Mac OS X.  It produces the answer:

```
21
s=-1  t=64
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're expecting.  The 21 is the greatest common denominator of 231 (11x7x3) and 525 (7x5x5x3).  I suspect the -1 is not correct (and therefore the 64 is probably wrong too).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

int algoritmoeuclides(int a, int b)
{
    if (a % b == 0)
        return b;
    return algoritmoeuclides(b, a % b);
}

std::pair<int, int>division(int dividendo, int divisor)
{
    int residuo = dividendo % divisor;
    int resultado = dividendo / divisor;
    return std::pair<int, int>(residuo, resultado);
}

std::pair<int, int>EuclidesExtendido(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return std::pair<int, int>(1, 0);
    else
    {
        std::pair<int, int>q = division(a, b);
        std::pair<int, int>s = EuclidesExtendido(b, q.second);
        return std::pair<int, int>(s.second, s.first - q.first * s.second);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 525;
    int b = 231;
    std::pair<int, int>p = EuclidesExtendido(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", algoritmoeuclides(a, b));
    printf("s=%d  t=%d\n", p.first, p.second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are fine with using some C++11 library features, instead of `std::pair<int, int>(s, t)` you want `std::tie(s, t)` from the `<tuple>` header which creates a pair of references that can be assigned to.